# Start External Process with Impersonate Issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, startprocessinfo

Im deploying my website onto my new server (windows 2003) from my local pc (windows 7) and my local homeserver (windows 2008) and have run in to a issue.

I have a process that starts up with the below code. It is passed a video file which gets converted.

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(Command, Parameters);
```

Them problem I have is on my new windows 2003 server it fails to work. No error or anything. Looking at the server and its taskmgr.exe I see the Process start but nothing happens.

Looking into it, everyone seems to say I need to have impersonate="true" in the webconfig which I do have, I currently have it set to the Administrator account which I use to log into remote desktop (I assume this is fine???)

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="Administrator" password="********" />
```

This still doesn't work.. Looking in the taskmgr.exe the process is started with the username ="NETWORK SERVICE" ...

Any ideas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A concrete solution i can't provide, but maybe this can help:

- Take a low level look with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to find if it is security related (missing permissions etc.)
- Build a Debug Version of your programm and insert some `Debug.Print()` statements to narrow the problem. These messages can be seen bei [Debug Viewer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx).
- Maybe it's a problem with a wrong or missing assembly. To find these problem take a look into the [Fusion Log Viewer](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx).

Maybe one of these techniques will help you to tackle down your problem.